# Why does this Python code give a runtime error when I try to upload it on kattis?

Tags: python

I'm keep getting a runtime error when trying to upload this assignment onto kattis: https://open.kattis.com/problems/qaly

I've already read the documentation on python from kattis, and changed the input to sys.stdin. Here is what I'm trying to upload:

```
QALY = 0
for i in range(1, int(sys.stdin[0])+1):
    QALY += float(sys.stdin[i].split(" ")[0])*float(sys.stdin[i].split(" ")[1])
print(QALY)
```

When I try it in pycharm using this code, it works:

```
f=open("/Users/lottehurkens/PycharmProjects/kattis/1.in", "r")
r = f.readlines()
QALY = 0
for i in range(1, int(r[0])+1):
    QALY += float(r[i].split(" ")[0])*float(r[i].split(" ")[1])
print(QALY)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error hidden by Kattis is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in range(1, int(sys.stdin[0])+1):
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

You can't use brackets on an `_io.TextIOWrapper` object like `sys.stdin` to retrieve a particular element of the input because it does not implement `__getitem__`.

You can use `input()` to retrieve one line of the input or you can transform `sys.stdin` into a list of lines with `sys.stdin.readlines()`.